# Is this an ideal way of testing code that inserts data to a table?

Tags: rest, symfony, post, tdd

I am working on implementing a REST API using Symfony2. I am trying to follow a Test Driven Development (TDD) approach. I am fairly new to both Symfony2 and TDD.

I have written this test:

```
public function testPost()
{
    // i) Make a request
    $client = static::createClient();
    $request = $client->request(
        'POST',
        '/api/outlets',
        array(),
        array(),
        array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'),
        '{"name":"Test Outlet"}'
    );

    // ii) Test the response
    $this->assertJsonResponse($client->getResponse(), 201, false);  

}
```

Which tests this controller action:

```
public function postAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Outlet();
    $form = $this->createForm(new OutletType(), $entity, array("method" => $request->getMethod()));
    $this->removeExtraFields($request, $form);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $entity;
    }

    return FOSView::create(array('errors' => $form->getErrors()), Codes::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

Everything works as expected.

Every time the test for the above action is run, it creates a new outlet in the database. Is this ideal? Or should I not be persisting data to the database in the test?

Comment: You have a choice, either mock the database or use a temporary database. For the latter, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142551/symfony2-phpunit-mocking-the-database-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to handle tests which involve database persistence. Sometimes you want to functionally test a form by filling the data, then submit the form, then check the status code and finally validate the content. Sometimes you need to load a set of fixtures beforehand.

Firstly you need isolate your tests in a test environnement, using a test database.

In app/config_test.yml:

```
...
doctrine:
    dbal:
        dbname: %database_name%_test
```

Then create the database and schema using `--env=test` option.

The easiest way to keep your database clean is to purge your test database before each test.

In your tests :

```
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Purger\ORMPurger;
...
protected function setUp()
{
    $this->client = static::createClient(array('environment' => 'test'));

    $purger = new ORMPurger($this->client->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager'));
    $purger->setPurgeMode(ORMPurger::PURGE_MODE_DELETE);
    $purger->purge();
}
```

If you do the purge in the `tearDown()` a test can potentially crash and the following tests won't have a clean database.

You need `"doctrine/data-fixtures"` in your dependencies.

Of course there's plenty of other solutions.